# Does not exist. No exception supplied error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have the following class based view.

```
class AllPluginsView(ListView):
    queryset = get_models(get_app('plugins'))
    template_name="console/plugins/plugins.html"
    context_object_name = "objects"
```

And following template,

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
    {% if object %}
        <td>{{ object }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

When I ask for the page, i get `DoesNotExist at /path/to/plugins
No exception supplied.` error. Any ideas ?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', AllPluginsView.as_view(),name='all-plugins'),
)
```

Comment: `queryset` needs to be a queryset, not a list (as returned by `get_models()` (I've never seen it done this way so I might be wrong)

Comment: get_models returns a list. Is there a way to convert list to a queryset

Comment: Also tried

    `class AllPluginsView(View):

        template_name="console/plugins/plugins.html"
        context_object_name = "objects"

        def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
            plugins= get_models(get_app('plugins'))
            return render(request, self.template_name,                 {'objects':plugins})` same result

Comment: I am wrong. [`queryset` can just be an iterable, not necessarily a `QuerySet`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L23)

Comment: Should `context_object_name = "objects"` be `context_object_name = "object"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's an import order thing? Try using `get_queryset` instead.

```
class AllPluginsView(ListView):
    template_name="console/plugins/plugins.html"
    context_object_name = "objects"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_models(get_app('plugins'))
```